# There is horiziontal scrollbar in IE7

Tags: css

So I have a website. I have set a larger image as a background:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {    
    color: #000;
    font: 100.1% sans-serif;
    background: #033361 url('/images/background2.jpg') center top no-repeat;
}
```

It works great in Firefox and IE8 but in IE7 the background is moved to the right and there is a horizontal scrollbar.

Can anyone explain this odd behaviour to me and suggest a solution?

My doctype:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

UPDATE:

It seems the problem is caused by my wrapper div:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1002px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

If I comment out the margin, the body background is centered correctly.

Comment: Do you have an appropriate standards compliant DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body{
   margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

Try that

Comment: The `html` doesn't have a default margin. The `padding` always defaults to zero.

Comment: It depends on the browser, it may have a margin, and it may have padding, I have had this same problem.

Comment: Both html and body have zero margin/padding. I'm using a reset css file from here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.